# Modernizr complete function seems to be getting ran too early

Tags: javascript, modernizr, excanvas

I have this javascript:

```
Modernizr.load([
    {
        test: Modernizr.canvas,
        nope: ['/assets/js/excanvas.js'],
        both: ['/assets/js/frank/pentool.js'],
        complete : function () {
            var cmo = new CutMeOut(settings);
        }
    }
]);
```

This loads in excanvas should canvas not be supported and when complete should fire the "complete" function. The CutMeOut class in `pentool.js` contains code that works with the canvas element. However, IE7 and IE8 are giving this error:

`Object doesn't support property or method`

If I just load `excanvas` normally the site works. So, how do I get `var cmo = new CutMeOut(settings);` to run after excanvas has pollyfilled the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: `Object doesn't support property or method` doesn't seem like the complete error.
What line is causing this? What property or method is not supported by what object?

Comment: In the CutMeOut class it is this line: `this.ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');`. I understand the problem I just need excanvas to fix it. However, it seems that using the complete function of Modernizr doesn't work.

Comment: I see. Would the loading [in here](http://modernizr.com/docs/#load) (ctrl+f `if ( !window.jQuery ) {`) do the trick?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I did use that method.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be work:

```
Modernizr.load([
    {
        load: '/assets/js/frank/pentool.js',
        complete: function() {

            if (!document.createElement('canvas').getContext) {
                Modernizr.load('/assets/js/excanvas.js');
            } else {
                var cmo = new CutMeOut(settings);
            }


        }

    },

    {

        complete: function() {
            if (!document.createElement('canvas').getContext) {
                window.addEvent('load', function() {
                    var cmo = new CutMeOut(settings);
                });
            }
        }
    }

]);
```